# R stacked bar reordering not working

Tags: r, stacked-chart

I am trying to re-order a stacked barplot in R with the tallest bars on left and the shortest on the right. This question is similar but I believe not identical to others because the typical approach to ordering stacked bars from left to right does not appear to be working for my data. I am using code that works on my other datasets ( x=reorder(aminoSet,-num) ) but in this case it does not. How can I arrange these bars properly? Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

s <- "aminoSet eth num
AE AFR 2
AK AFR 1
AL AFR 1
AT AFR 1
AV EAS 1
DE AFR 4
DE AMR 1
DE EAS 4
DE EUR 2
DE SAS 2
EK AFR 1
EK EAS 1
ER AFR 1
GT AFR 1
HS AFR 1
LS AFR 1
MP AFR 1
MP SAS 1
PS AFR 1
PS EAS 1
PT AFR 1
RS EAS 1"
counts <- read.delim(textConnection(s),header=T,sep = " ")


g <- ggplot(counts[order(counts$eth,decreasing=T),], aes(x=reorder(aminoSet,-num),group=num, y=num))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = eth),stat = "identity") + theme_bw() + theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

I get the following image which is not ordered properly from left to right:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you're re-leveling the factor according to num, and the default is to take the mean. So for EK, MP, and PS, that would be 1, but you want it to be 2. Just change the function in `reorder` and you should be good to go.

```
counts %>% 
  mutate(aminoSet = reorder(aminoSet, -num, sum)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(aminoSet, num)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = eth))
```

[image]